# Optimizing .gs search & replace script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Hoping someone could just point out my probably obvious mistakes.

Code searches a Data page & copies matched info to a Results page. This is fine & works quickly.
What happens is when I add an overwrite section to the script. It overwrites matched entries as "Done" on the data page, so if the Data page gets added to, the previous entries won't match again.

I have 2 variants I've tried that *work* but are quite slow...as in you can sit & watch each match change to "Done" once every few seconds.

Appreciate any insight.

Here's the code:

```
function cellMatch() {
  // Sheet Import
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Raw_Data"); // Data
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Pallet_Data");// Result
  var sheet3 = ss.getSheetByName("Close");// Search
  // Data Import
  var lr = sheet1.getLastRow();
  var data = sheet1.getRange(2,1,lr-1,2).getValues();
  var lc = sheet2.getLastColumn()+1;
  var key = sheet3.getRange("A2").getValue();
  var matched = [["Pallet "+lc+" ("+key+")"]];

  //Start
  for (var i=0; i<lr-1; i++) {
    if (data[i][1] == key) {
      var temp = [];
      temp.push(data[i][0]);
      matched.push(temp);
    
// Slow Overwrite-----------------------------------
/*
if(i>0){
  var temp1 = sheet1.getRange(i,2).getValue();
  var temp2 = sheet1.getRange(i+1,2).getValue();
  var temp3 = sheet1.getRange(i+2,2).getValue();
    // Testing1
    if(temp1 == key ){
      sheet1.getRange(i,2).setValue("Done");
    } 
    if (i== lr-2){
      if (temp2 == key){
          sheet1.getRange(i+1,2).setValue("Done");
       }
      if (temp3 == key){
         sheet1.getRange(i+2,2).setValue("Done");
       }
    }
} 
*/    
  }

  // Shorter code but even slower overwrite----------------
/*
  for(var i=1; i<=lr; i++){
    var temp1 = sheet1.getRange(i,2).getValue();
    if(temp1 == key){
      sheet1.getRange(i,2).setValue("Done");
     }
   }
*/

// Location Update ---------------------------------
    var A7 = sheet3.getRange("A7");
    A7.setValue(matched);

// Data Write -----------------------------------------
  var result = sheet2.getRange(1,lc,matched.length);
  result.setValues(matched);

}
```

Link to the [Test Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bm-hNS2YioSDd9B7-EFXt7WC2di_QLKu4YeIuazNZ-o/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution:

The script runs slow because there are API calls in `for` loops. Best practice is to manipulate only the array inside the loop and do the API calls before and after the loop.

In your code it would look like this:

```
function cellMatch() {
  // Sheet Import
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Raw_Data"); // Data
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Pallet_Data");// Result
  var sheet3 = ss.getSheetByName("Close");// Search
  // Data Import
  var lr = sheet1.getLastRow();
  var datarange = sheet1.getRange(2,1,lr-1,2);
  var data = datarange.getValues();
  var lc = sheet2.getLastColumn()+1;
  var key = sheet3.getRange("A2").getValue();
  var matched = [["Pallet "+lc+" ("+key+")"]];

  //Start
  for (var i=0; i<lr-1; i++) {
    if (data[i][1] == key) {
      var temp = [];
      temp.push(data[i][0]);
      matched.push(temp);
      data[i][1] = "Done";
    }

// Location Update ---------------------------------
    var A7 = sheet3.getRange("A7");
    A7.setValue(matched);

// Data Write -----------------------------------------
  datarange.setValues(data);
  var result = sheet2.getRange(1,lc,matched.length);
  result.setValues(matched);
}
```

Note that the `for` loop does not have any getValue()/setValue() methods.

This has the same effect on your sample sheet, only way faster.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that!! If you don't mind, why won't just ```data[i][1] = "Done"``` work without the ```datarange.setValues(data)```?  I had tried something similar before, thinking it would write on each loop. It makes in context how you implemented it.

Comment: ````data```` is only an internal array in the script, copied when ````getValues()```` was used earlier. You still need to use ````setValues(data)```` to apply it to the sheet.